# /nagios/cgi-bin/statusmap.cgi was not found on this server

Tags: ubuntu-12.10, nagios

I installed Nagios 3.4.4 on Ubuntu server 12.10. Installation was successful but now I'm not able to view maps and trends. When I try, I get the following error
**`/nagios/cgi-bin/statusmap.cgi was not found on this server`**

Why is this happening?
What should be done for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other CGIs are working, you're possibly missing some dependent library (most likely a graphics library) which wasn't properly checked for by the package.

If you execute the cgi program from the CLI, or run `ldd` against them the linker should tell you if that's the case.